# How can I rename a corrupt file without using CHKDSK?

Tags: windows-xp, rename, chkdsk, file-corruption

How can I rename a corrupt file without using CHKDSK? It's a remote PC and I am not allowed to reboot it. Is there a way to fix or rename the file without rebooting?

Comment: How do you know that this file is corrupted?

Comment: You could try to rename the file and remove the extension. EG, rename from myfile.txt to ThisNewNameFile (note, no .txt)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the file name is corrupt.

Two ways to rename the file:

1. Use Windows Explorer. Open the folder containing the file, and select the file. Press F2 (or right-click the file and choose Rename). Then type a new name.
2. Use a Windows Command Prompt. Open a Command Prompt and change to the Drive and Folder (CD) containing the file. Then type:

   ren "currentname.ext" "newname.ext"

   If the (corrupted) filename contains characters that you are not able to type, use "wildcards" to specify the corrupted filename.

   For example...  use "?" (question marks) to represent non typable characters in the filename like:

   ren "so?me?fi?le?.ext" "newname.ext"

If you are having trouble with this, or if I have misunderstood your question, perhaps you could update your question to include more details.

If the file is open and locked by another process, it is likely these attempts will fail.  In that case, you will need to close or unlock the file first.

If all these attempts fail, perhaps you could have a user who has a local account on the machine try to rename the file.